# Can I delete MYD-XXXXXX.BAK files in mariaDB?

Tags: mariadb

I've found that most of the hard disk space on the server is due to the database.

Currently, the capacity of the database being served as a web accounted for 180GB out of 250GB.

Looking at `/var/lib/mysql/MyDB`,
`TableName.MYD-XXXXXXXXXXXX.BAK` file occupied most of the capacity.

Assuming there is no problem with the current database, can I delete this file myself? Or is there a better way to reduce the capacity?

Comment: Sounds like some backup program, not MariaDB.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839052/can-i-safely-remove-bak-files-from-mysql-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files are from `aria_chk` or `myisamchk` when the `--backup` option is used.

As there's no problem with the current database tables, these `.BAK` files can be removed.

Comment: Can I use ```sudo rm *.BAK``` in the console ?

Comment: yes, that will work.